# Set boolean input property via attribute presence on directive

Tags: angular

I can add an input property to a directive and set it by passing a value such as

```
<my-component [customInput]='true'></my-component>
```

But for boolean input properties, I can't figure out how to set the value via presence/lack-of-presence of the input on a directive. i.e.

```
<my-component customInput></my-component>
```

When I try this, the `customInput` is not set, when I would like it to be set to `true`. Any ideas how I can accomplish this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out an input property which is present but has no value (i.e. `<my-component customInput></my-component>`) is set to an empty string `""`.

So `<my-component customInput></my-component>` works so long as I add a setter function to the input to coerce the value. Something like

```
@Input() customInput(value: string | boolean) {
  if (typeof value === 'string' {
    this._customInput = true;
  }
  else {
    this._customInput = value;
  }
}
```

I'll also note that using an input binding without a value like `<my-component [customInput]></my-component>` results in `customInput` not being set.